# Why my border color doesn't change even If I already tried it using specific value

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry if the title make you confused, I wonder my table border suddenly lost it color

```css
  #my-table table {
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #1d3962;
    margin: 0% auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    border: none;
    border-top: none;
  }

  #my-table tr{
      border-top: solid 2px rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.1);
  }

  #my-table tr:nth-child(1){
      border-top: none;
  }

  #my-table tr:nth-last-child(1){
      border-bottom: none;
  }


  #my-table td{
   width: 25%;
  }

  #my-table .first{
      border-top: solid 2px rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.4);
  }

  #my-table tr td:nth-child(1){
    padding: 0px 0px;
  }

  #my-table tr th:nth-child(2){
   font-weight: bold;
 background-color: rgba(46, 207, 47, 0.1);
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    padding: 32px 38px;
  }

  #my-table tr td:nth-child(2){
 background-color: rgba(46, 207, 47, 0.1);
    padding: 32px 38px;
  }

  #my-table tr th:nth-child(3){
   font-weight: bold;
 background-color: rgba(219, 206, 44, 0.1);
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    padding: 32px 38px;
  }

  #my-table tr td:nth-child(3){
 background-color: rgba(219, 206, 44, 0.1);
    padding: 32px 38px;
  }

  #my-table tr th:nth-child(4){
   font-weight: bold;
 background-color: rgba(229, 76, 110, 0.1);
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    padding: 32px 38px;
  }

  #my-table tr td:nth-child(4){
 color: #E54C6E;
 background-color: rgba(229, 76, 110, 0.1);
    padding: 32px 38px;
 margin: 0% 15px;
  }

  #my-table .test{
   padding-right: 20px;
  }

  #my-table tr td{
    padding: 32px 38px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body id="my-table">


<!--main division-->

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>test</th>
      <th>Free</th>
    </tr>

 <tr class="first">
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the snippet above, my table give back the border color but when I try it in my web the color itself is gone, even I put it the code and the css like I make in the snippet the color is lost

[image: You can see at the border top, the color is lost]

can someone help me to solve this? or tell me what's wrong with my code

Comment: Clear your cache maybe? Border works fine for me

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the elements in the browser and using the styles pane to see if any of the styles are being overridden or computed incorrectly? There could be other CSS on your website with a higher order of preference. Meaning it works on SO because that is the only CSS, but your site could be loading other CSS that is overriding it.

Comment: @abney317 Thank you for your response, I tried to clear the cache but still no luck

Comment: Your css might be overrides by some other css. Try to use !important with your css style.

Comment: @react-dev Thank you for your response, I think the chance it overide is low, since I always specify the component using `id` for every component, but is my thought wrong? can it still overide even I'm using `id` for every component ?

Comment: @RakishFrisky yes it can still be override using `!important`

Comment: `id` selector does not guarantee it will be applied no. See [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Note that the use of `!important` should only be used when trying to override foreign CSS and using `!important` is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the table border then please modify the below css:

```
#my-table table {
    border: none; // Remove this line
    border-top: none; // Remove this line
    border: 1px solid red; // Add this line
  }
```

Comment: Thnak you for your answer, when I try your code, the outer border change it color to red, but not with the inner border, but the fun fact is, it give me a new condition to try, I fix my problem after add the width around `3px` such as `border-top: solid 3px rgba(58, 115, 197, 0.4)` I still don't know why the `1px` and `2px` the border width doesn't change the color, do you know why?

Comment: Glad to know that you are on the way to solve your problem. Border width value increases the height of the color you set for the border. It's never changed the color. 
This is the working mechanism of *border* property as far I know.